# Get field (property) initial values from JS class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

Is it possible to recover the values assigned to class fields (properties?  not sure of best js terminology.) from the class object.  For instance, suppose I have the following class:

```
class Foo {
   bar = [1, 2 ,3]
    
   constructor() {
      this.bar.pop();
      this.bar.pop();
   }
}
```

I'd like to be able to programmatically recover the initial ([1,2,3]) value of bar even though it is overwritten in the constructor preferably *without* modifying the existing class Foo.

The original motivation is that it's a pain to copy over and keep in sync all the initialization values when running tests on a complex class initialization sequence.  However, I realize I don't really understand what's going on in terms of the underlying object model so I'd love a why as well.  Like are class fields setting some property on a prototype object or constructor somewhere?

Comment: Can you expand a bit on "*copy over and keep in sync all the initialization values when running tests on a complex class initialization sequence*", please?

Comment: Sure, say I have a class which uses a bunch of defaults that really don't affect other code (maybe it does crypto over some group or ECC and I need to choose some generators for the group which are fixed and never need to be changed or used elsewhere).  I do some complex manipulation in constructor so I need to test that it came out right and I need the initial data for that.  I'd prefer not to pull it out of class and make it its own export or make the class ugly by keeping shadow copies but I guess moving it out of class isn't end of the world.

Comment: Values that are fixed and never change could easily be made a `static` member of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> are class fields setting some property on a prototype object

No. They are not accessible from the class object.

> or constructor somewhere?

Yes, fields are syntactic sugar over creating properties in the constructor. Your code is equivalent to

```
class Foo {
   constructor() {
      this.bar = [1, 2 ,3];
      this.bar.pop();
      this.bar.pop();
   }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thx so much.  I was thinking libraries like mobx somehow track changes to these objects.  But I guess this is why subclassing is limited there.  Still it sounded like there was some difference between annotated and unannotated fields/methods as to whether they could be observed so I thought maybe you could here too...or I am just confused.  Sorry, for trying to get you to answer a further question after your excellent response.

Comment: @PeterGerdes i don't know mobx in details, but I suspect it's just making them observable after the instance is created - at which point they are indistinguishable from other properties, no matter through what syntax they were added to the object. The only thing for which it might make a difference is decorators, which might act on syntactic elements of the class depending on what version of the proposal you're using.

Answer (score 1):

If you modify shadow-copy of the variable,

OR

You could store items that you pop in another variable.

as in

```
class Foo {
   bar = [1, 2 ,3];

   deleted = [];
    
   constructor() {
      deleted = this.bar.pop();
   }
}
```

Be careful with overwriting ***deleted***

Comment: I mean yah, I know how to not change them but I didn't want to pollute my working code with stuff just for tests and make it ugly...but I guess I can't.  But I found out how it works which is the bigger issue.  So thanks grearly!